# How to extract android jetpack compose testTags in appium?

Tags: appium, android-jetpack-compose, android-espresso

My team is looking to do automated functional testing.
Once our developers started using jetpack compose, we lost most of our selectors.
I try to extract the testTags provided by compose.

here is th appium2 capabilities, built on the [Raj Varlma's medium article - Automating Android Jetpack Compose using Appium](https://medium.com/bumble-tech/automating-android-jetpack-compose-using-appium-edb760fe79b9) using emulated pixel3A with api 30 in Appium Inspector :

```
{
  "platformName": "Android",
  "appium:app": "/Users/j.faux/Desktop/mobileApps/android/noFlippr.apk",
  "appium:device": "emulator-5554",
  "appium:platformVersion": "11",
  "appium:automationName": "Espresso",
  "appium:espressoBuildConfig": "{\"additionalAndroidTestDependencies\": [\"androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0\", \"androidx.activity:activity:1.3.1\",  \"androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6\", \"androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1\"]}",
  "appium:skipUnlock": true,
  "appium:fullReset": false,
  "appium:forceEspressoRebuild": true,
  "appium:showGradleLog": true
}
```

Here's a sample of the xml generated code from UIautomator2:

```
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView index="0" package="sport.android.poufpouf.fr.qa" class="androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView" text="" resource-id="sport.android.poufpouf.fr.qa:id/compose_view" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,124][1080,271]" displayed="true">
                  <android.view.View index="0" package="sport.android.poufpouf.fr.qa" class="android.view.View" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,124][1080,271]" displayed="true">
                    <android.view.View index="0" package="sport.android.poufpouf.fr.qa" class="android.view.View" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[552,134][678,260]" displayed="true">
```

I cannot run the apk running the above conf.
Espresso seems to achieve its build.

Here are appium logs

```
➜  ~ appium server -p 9000 -a 127.0.0.1 -pa /wd/hub 
...
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices
[debug] [ADB] Connected devices: [{"udid":"emulator-5554","state":"device"}]
[AndroidDriver] Looking for a device with Android '11.0.0'
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 11
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 start-server'
[debug] [ADB] Setting device id to emulator-5554
[BaseDriver] Using local app '/Users/j.faux/Desktop/mobileApps/android/appiumCompose/noFlippr2.apk'
[debug] [ADB] Checking app cert for /Users/j.faux/Desktop/mobileApps/android/appiumCompose/noFlippr2.apk
[ADB] Using 'apksigner.jar' from '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/33.0.1/lib/apksigner.jar'
[debug] [ADB] Starting apksigner: /Users/j.faux/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk\@11/11.0.17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Xss1m -jar /Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/33.0.1/lib/apksigner.jar verify --print-certs /Users/j.faux/Desktop/mobileApps/android/appiumCompose/noFlippr2.apk
[debug] [ADB] apksigner stdout: Signer #1 certificate DN: EMAILADDRESS=android@android.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
[debug] [ADB] Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: a40da80a59d170caa950cf15c18c454d47a39b26989d8b640ecd745ba71bf5dc
[debug] [ADB] Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 61ed377e85d386a8dfee6b864bd85b0bfaa5af81
[debug] [ADB] Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: e89b158e4bcf988ebd09eb83f5378e87
[debug] [ADB] 
[debug] [ADB] sha256 hash did match for 'noFlippr2.apk'
[ADB] '/Users/j.faux/Desktop/mobileApps/android/appiumCompose/noFlippr2.apk' is signed with the default certificate
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] EspressoDriver version: 2.13.8
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 30
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 11
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 30
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell 'settings put global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps 1;settings put global hidden_api_policy_p_apps 1;settings put global hidden_api_policy 1''
[ADB] Package name: 'sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa'
[ADB] Main activity name: 'reg.poufpouf.sport.features.splash.SplashActivity'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Parsed package and activity are: sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa/reg.poufpouf.sport.features.splash.SplashActivity
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device'
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell echo ping'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to device...
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[debug] [ADB] 'io.appium.settings' is installed
[debug] [ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.settings'
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[debug] [ADB] The version name of the installed 'io.appium.settings' is greater or equal to the application version name ('4.2.4' >= '4.2.4')
[debug] [ADB] There is no need to install/upgrade '/Users/j.faux/.appium/node_modules/appium-espresso-driver/node_modules/io.appium.settings/apks/settings_apk-debug.apk'
[debug] [ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell 'pgrep --help; echo $?''
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] io.appium.settings is already running. There is no need to reset its permissions.
[debug] [Logcat] Starting logs capture with command: /Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 logcat -v threadtime
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell settings get global animator_duration_scale'
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell settings get global transition_animation_scale'
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell settings get global window_animation_scale'
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Forwarding Espresso Server port 6791 to 8300
[debug] [ADB] Forwarding system: 8300 to device: 6791
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:8300 tcp:6791'
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] 'skipUnlock' capability set, so skipping device unlock
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa'
[debug] [ADB] 'sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa' is installed
[debug] [ADB] Getting package info for 'sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa'
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa'
[debug] [ADB] The version name of the installed 'sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa' is greater or equal to the application version name ('6.0.5' >= '6.0.5')
[debug] [ADB] There is no need to install/upgrade '/Users/j.faux/Desktop/mobileApps/android/appiumCompose/noFlippr2.apk'
[AndroidDriver] Performing fast reset on 'sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa'
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa'
[debug] [ADB] 'sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa' is installed
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa'
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm clear sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Performed fast reset on the installed 'sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa' application (stop and clear)
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] 'forceEspressoRebuild' capability is enabled
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Deleting the obsolete Espresso server package '/var/folders/zk/cnc6rrjd067dr2bjwx6s2y1w0000gp/T/io.appium.espressoserver.test_2.13.8_sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa_emulator-5554.apk'
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Loading the build configuration from 'espressoBuildConfig' capability
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Building espresso server in '/var/folders/zk/cnc6rrjd067dr2bjwx6s2y1w0000gp/T/espresso-server-emulator-5554'
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] The build folder root could be customized by changing the 'tmpDir' capability
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Copying espresso server template from ('/Users/j.faux/.appium/node_modules/appium-espresso-driver/espresso-server' to '/var/folders/zk/cnc6rrjd067dr2bjwx6s2y1w0000gp/T/espresso-server-emulator-5554')
[debug] [Support] Traversed 52 directories and 281 files in 164ms
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Bulding espresso server
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Adding the following additionalAndroidTestDependencies to build.gradle.kts: androidTestImplementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"),androidTestImplementation("androidx.activity:activity:1.3.1"),androidTestImplementation("androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6"),androidTestImplementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1")
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Beginning build with command '/var/folders/zk/cnc6rrjd067dr2bjwx6s2y1w0000gp/T/espresso-server-emulator-5554/gradlew -PappiumTargetPackage=sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa app:assembleAndroidTest' in directory '/var/folders/zk/cnc6rrjd067dr2bjwx6s2y1w0000gp/T/espresso-server-emulator-5554'
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Output from Gradle will be logged. To change this, use 'showGradleLog' desired capability
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:generateDebugResValues FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:mergeDebugResources FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:processDebugManifest FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:processDebugResources FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:bundleDebugClasses FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild SKIPPED
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl NO-SOURCE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:checkDebugAndroidTestAarMetadata FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:processDebugAndroidTestResources FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:javaPreCompileDebugAndroidTest FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders NO-SOURCE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:compressDebugAndroidTestAssets FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:processDebugAndroidTestJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestJniLibFolders FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:checkDebugAndroidTestDuplicateClasses FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:desugarDebugAndroidTestFileDependencies FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:mergeExtDexDebugAndroidTest FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:mergeLibDexDebugAndroidTest FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:dexBuilderDebugAndroidTest FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebugAndroidTest FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:validateSigningDebugAndroidTest FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:writeDebugAndroidTestSigningConfigVersions FROM-CACHE
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestJavaResource
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:packageDebugAndroidTest
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:assembleDebugAndroidTest
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] > Task :app:assembleAndroidTest
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] 
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Gradle] [STDOUT] 37 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 34 from cache
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Copying built apk from '/var/folders/zk/cnc6rrjd067dr2bjwx6s2y1w0000gp/T/espresso-server-emulator-5554/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk' to '/var/folders/zk/cnc6rrjd067dr2bjwx6s2y1w0000gp/T/io.appium.espressoserver.test_2.13.8_sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa_emulator-5554.apk'
[debug] [ADB] Checking app cert for /var/folders/zk/cnc6rrjd067dr2bjwx6s2y1w0000gp/T/io.appium.espressoserver.test_2.13.8_sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa_emulator-5554.apk
[debug] [ADB] Starting apksigner: /Users/j.faux/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk\@11/11.0.17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Xss1m -jar /Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/33.0.1/lib/apksigner.jar verify --print-certs /var/folders/zk/cnc6rrjd067dr2bjwx6s2y1w0000gp/T/io.appium.espressoserver.test_2.13.8_sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa_emulator-5554.apk
[debug] [ADB] apksigner stdout: Signer #1 certificate DN: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug
[debug] [ADB] Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: 55634d7b56020fd4cd3c4d8d9191f62887748be325c4210d4911a957b6ae5e08
[debug] [ADB] Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: b1d36cbdc548036ee0070a5a857f96fae6bcd58e
[debug] [ADB] Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: 733bc344585729cdeac947b1753891ee
[debug] [ADB] 
[ADB] '/var/folders/zk/cnc6rrjd067dr2bjwx6s2y1w0000gp/T/io.appium.espressoserver.test_2.13.8_sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa_emulator-5554.apk' is signed with a non-default certificate
[ADB] Using 'zipalign' from '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/33.0.1/zipalign'
[debug] [ADB] /var/folders/zk/cnc6rrjd067dr2bjwx6s2y1w0000gp/T/io.appium.espressoserver.test_2.13.8_sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa_emulator-5554.apk' is already zip-aligned. Doing nothing
[debug] [ADB] Signing '/var/folders/zk/cnc6rrjd067dr2bjwx6s2y1w0000gp/T/io.appium.espressoserver.test_2.13.8_sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa_emulator-5554.apk' with default cert
[debug] [ADB] Uninstalling io.appium.espressoserver.test
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.espressoserver.test
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.espressoserver.test'
[debug] [ADB] 'io.appium.espressoserver.test' is installed
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop io.appium.espressoserver.test'
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 uninstall io.appium.espressoserver.test'
[debug] [ADB] 'adb uninstall io.appium.espressoserver.test' command output: Success
[ADB] io.appium.espressoserver.test was successfully uninstalled
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Uninstalled the obsolete Espresso server package from the device under test
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.espressoserver.test
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.espressoserver.test'
[debug] [ADB] 'io.appium.espressoserver.test' is not installed
[debug] [ADB] App '/var/folders/zk/cnc6rrjd067dr2bjwx6s2y1w0000gp/T/io.appium.espressoserver.test_2.13.8_sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa_emulator-5554.apk' is not installed
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Installing Espresso Test Server apk from the target device (path: '/var/folders/zk/cnc6rrjd067dr2bjwx6s2y1w0000gp/T/io.appium.espressoserver.test_2.13.8_sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa_emulator-5554.apk')
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 help'
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 features'
[ADB] The application at '/var/folders/zk/cnc6rrjd067dr2bjwx6s2y1w0000gp/T/io.appium.espressoserver.test_2.13.8_sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa_emulator-5554.apk' will not be cached, because the device under test has confirmed the support of streamed installs
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 install /var/folders/zk/cnc6rrjd067dr2bjwx6s2y1w0000gp/T/io.appium.espressoserver.test_2.13.8_sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa_emulator-5554.apk'
[ADB] The installation of 'io.appium.espressoserver.test_2.13.8_sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa_emulator-5554.apk' took 166ms
[debug] [ADB] Install command stdout: Serving...
[debug] [ADB] Performing Incremental Install
[debug] [ADB] Success
[debug] [ADB] Install command complete in 153 ms
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Installed Espresso Test Server apk '/var/folders/zk/cnc6rrjd067dr2bjwx6s2y1w0000gp/T/io.appium.espressoserver.test_2.13.8_sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa_emulator-5554.apk' (pkg: 'io.appium.espressoserver.test')
[ADB] Adding packages ["io.appium.settings","io.appium.espressoserver.test"] to Doze whitelist
[debug] [ADB] Got the following command chunks to execute: [["dumpsys","deviceidle","whitelist","+io.appium.settings",";","dumpsys","deviceidle","whitelist","+io.appium.espressoserver.test",";"]]
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys deviceidle whitelist +io.appium.settings ; dumpsys deviceidle whitelist +io.appium.espressoserver.test ;'
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Performing cleanup of automation leftovers
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] No obsolete sessions have been detected (socket hang up)
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Starting Espresso Server v2.13.8 with cmd: adb shell am instrument -w -e debug false -e disableAnalytics true io.appium.espressoserver.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
[debug] [ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","am","instrument","-w","-e","debug",false,"-e","disableAnalytics",true,"io.appium.espressoserver.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"]
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Waiting up to 45000ms for Espresso server to be online
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8300/status] with no body
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] socket hang up
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Instrumentation] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{io.appium.espressoserver.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner} from pid=21062, uid=21062 not allowed because package io.appium.espressoserver.test does not have a signature matching the target sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Instrumentation] java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{io.appium.espressoserver.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner} from pid=21062, uid=21062 not allowed because package io.appium.espressoserver.test does not have a signature matching the target sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Instrumentation] at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2373)
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)]    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] [Instrumentation] at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)]    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2282)
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)]    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startInstrumentation(IActivityManager.java:6090)
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)]    at com.android.commands.am.Instrument.run(Instrument.java:517)
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)]    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:202)
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)]    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:80)
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)]    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:60)
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)]    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:50)
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)]    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)]    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:399)
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)]    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startInstrumentation(ActivityManagerService.java:16921)
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)]    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2655)
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)]    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2883)
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)]    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1154)
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)]    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Instrumentation process exited with code 1 from signal null
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Espresso server process has been unexpectedly terminated. Check the Appium server log and the logcat output for more details
[debug] [EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Deleting espresso session
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys activity services io.appium.settings/.recorder.RecorderService'
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop sport.android.poufpouf.com.qa'
[debug] [Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[EspressoDriver@dbfa (c1141684)] Restoring hidden api policy to the device default configuration
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell 'settings delete global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy''
[debug] [ADB] Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8300 
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/j.faux/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward --remove tcp:8300'
[debug] [AppiumDriver@f569] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1672050778899 (11:32:58 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time))
[debug] [AppiumDriver@f569] Encountered internal error running command: A new session could not be created. Details: Espresso server process has been unexpectedly terminated. Check the Appium server log and the logcat output for more details. Check https://github.com/appium/appium-espresso-driver#troubleshooting regarding advanced session startup troubleshooting.
[debug] [AppiumDriver@f569] Error: Espresso server process has been unexpectedly terminated. Check the Appium server log and the logcat output for more details. Check https://github.com/appium/appium-espresso-driver#troubleshooting regarding advanced session startup troubleshooting.
[debug] [AppiumDriver@f569]     at Object.errorAndThrow (/Users/j.faux/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/support/lib/logging.js:115:34)
[debug] [AppiumDriver@f569]     at condFn (/Users/j.faux/.appium/node_modules/appium-espresso-driver/lib/espresso-runner.js:287:20)
[debug] [AppiumDriver@f569]     at spin (/Users/j.faux/.appium/node_modules/appium-espresso-driver/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:221:26)
[debug] [AppiumDriver@f569]     at spin (/Users/j.faux/.appium/node_modules/appium-espresso-driver/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:231:20)
[debug] [AppiumDriver@f569]     at waitForCondition (/Users/j.faux/.appium/node_modules/appium-espresso-driver/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:238:10)
[debug] [AppiumDriver@f569]     at EspressoRunner.startSession (/Users/j.faux/.appium/node_modules/appium-espresso-driver/lib/espresso-runner.js:281:7)
[debug] [AppiumDriver@f569]     at EspressoDriver.startEspressoSession (/Users/j.faux/.appium/node_modules/appium-espresso-driver/lib/driver.js:444:5)
[debug] [AppiumDriver@f569]     at EspressoDriver.createSession (/Users/j.faux/.appium/node_modules/appium-espresso-driver/lib/driver.js:224:7)
[debug] [AppiumDriver@f569]     at AppiumDriver.createSession (/Users/j.faux/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:336:35)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 8111 ms - 1689
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same issue as you had and took a look into the documentation of "Compose" for Android:

[Android Compose TestTags](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/semantics/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.semantics.SemanticsPropertyReceiver).testTagsAsResourceId())

Inside you will find information about `testTag` and `testTagsAsResourceId`.
Ask your Dev to add the `testTag` to every compose element you need to interact with, as well as turning the `testTagsAsResourceId` to true.

In the Appium Inspector, you can (and should) switch to UiAutomator2 driver, and try to use the following capabilities:

```
{
    "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
    "platformName": "Android",
    "appium:platformVersion": (insert the version of your current device),
    "appium:espressoBuildConfig": "{\"additionalAndroidTestDependencies\": [\"androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1\", \"androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0\",\"androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6\"]}"
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem!